# Data is not updated, have to refresh the page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an MongoDB update query in nodejs to update the price according to the no of days each day charge 5rs, but I have to refresh the data to update, it is not been updating automatically.

```
getDashboard(req, res){
                console.log(req.user._id)
                Dashboard.find({studentId: req.user._id},null,{sort: {'createdAt': -1}}, (err, foundBook) =>{
                    Student.findOne({_id:req.user._id},async (err, result)=>{
                        if(foundBook){
                            if(result){
                                const charges = getPenalty(foundBook);
                                const returnDate =  charges[0];
                                const obj = charges[1];

                                if(moment().isAfter(returnDate)){
                                    obj.forEach(async (singleObj) => {
     // this is update query     const updated = await Dashboard.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:singleObj.id},{$set:{"charge":singleObj.charge}},{upsert:true})
                                            if(updated){
                                                console.log("updated");
                                            }else{
                                                console.log(err)
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                                    await res.render('student/dashboard',{foundBook: foundBook, moment : moment, returnDate : returnDate, result:result})
                                }
                            }else{
                                console.log(err)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    })
                
            }
```

this is the file to calculate the charge per day

```
const getPenalty = (foundBook) =>{
    let obj = [];

    
    var returnDate, currentDate, penalty, days_diff;
    var price = 5

    foundBook.forEach((book) =>{
        
        var chargePerBook = {
            id : " ",
            charge : ""
        }
        currentDate = moment(new Date())
        returnDate = moment(book.createdAt).add(7, 'days')
        days_diff = currentDate.diff(returnDate,'days')
        penalty = days_diff * price;
        
        chargePerBook.id = book._id;
        chargePerBook.charge = penalty;
        
        obj.push(chargePerBook)
    })
    return [returnDate,obj];


}
```

I want to update it automatically when I get into dashboard page I don't want to refresh it again.

Comment: If you uncomment the update query, you are not getting the expected behaviour?

Comment: it is uncommented but here i have given the comment. Yeah its not giving me expected behaviour